# Suggestions for long and wide table

Tags: tables, landscape, supertabular

I want to add a "set" of tables in a document. Something like that

[image]

I thought of combing somehow `supertabular` for spliting in pages and `landscape` in order to rotate it...

I don't know how to achieve it or if there is another better solution.
Any ideas will be more than welcomed!!!

A "minimum" effort is the following

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{units}

\newcommand{\kai}{\quad \text{και} \quad}
\newcommand{\kkai}{\qquad \text{και} \qquad}
\newcommand{\sw}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\sq}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}
\newcommand{\gre}[1]{\greektext\latintext#1}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}%I forgot to add it...Sorry
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}\sq
\begin{table}
%\hspace{-1cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{supertabular}    {|C{0.3cm}|C{2.7cm}|C{1.6cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1.4cm}|C{1.3cm}|C{1.8cm}|C{1.8cm}|C{1.8cm}|C{1.5cm}    |C{1.5cm}|C{1.5cm}|C{1cm}|}
        \hline

    {} & \textbf{\eng{Time} \eng{(UT)}\newline \eng{(hh:mm:ss)}} & $\mathbf{O_3(corr)}$ \newline \textbf{\eng{(DU)}} & $\mathbf{O_3(1/2)}$ \newline \textbf{\eng{(DU)}} & $\mathbf{O_3(2/3)}$ \newline \textbf{\eng{(DU)}} & \textbf{\eng{SZA}} \newline \eng{({}$\mathbf{{}^o}$)} & \textbf{\eng{SI}}\newline($\mathbf{305nm}$) \newline ($\mathbf{\times 10^{-6}}$)\newline ($\mathbf{W/m^2}$) & \textbf{\eng{SI}}\newline($\mathbf{312nm}$) \newline ($\mathbf{\times 10^{-4}}$)\newline ($\mathbf{W/m^2}$) & \textbf{\eng{SI}}\newline($\mathbf{320nm}$) \newline ($\mathbf{\times 10^{-3}}$)\newline ($\mathbf{W/m^2}$) & \textbf{\eng{Signal}}\newline($\mathbf{305nm}$) \newline \textbf{(\eng{mV})} &  \textbf{\eng{Signal}}\newline($\mathbf{312nm}$) \newline \textbf{(\eng{mV})} &  \textbf{\eng{Signal}}\newline($\mathbf{320nm}$) \newline \textbf{(\eng{mV})} & \textbf{T} \newline ({}$\mathbf{{}^oC}$)\\
    \hline
    ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{1}$ & $13:42:28$ & $287.1$ & $264.7$ & $231.4$ & $77.023$ & $46.6$ & $17.9$ & $8.78$ & $0.63$ & $6.73$ & $16.95$ & $24.9$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{2}$ & $13:45:05$ & $294.1$ & $267.6$ & $229.9$ & $77.415$ & $34.2$ & $15.1$ & $7.64$ & $0.46$ & $5.66$ & $16.48$ & $25.3$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{3}$ & $13:47:33$ & $294.6$ & $267.6$ & $229.1$ & $77.788$ & $26.3$ & $12.7$ & $6.71$ & $0.36$ & $4.79$ & $14.47$ & $25.1$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{4}$ & $13:51:19$ & $306.7$ & $273.8$ & $286.9$ & $78.361$ & $15.7$ & $9.08$ & $5.39$ & $0.21$ & $3.64$ & $11.63$ & $24.7$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{5}$ & $13:54:20$ & $323.0$ & $282.9$ & $225.7$ & $78.824$ & $9.71$ & $7.75$ & $4.55$ & $0.13$ & $2.92$ & $9.82$ & $37.6$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{6}$ & $--:--:--$ & $432.1$ & $345.6$ & $221.8$ & $79.818$ & $1.68$ & $4.65$ & $3.07$ & $0.02$ & $1.75$ & $6.62$ & $23.5$\\
    \hline
    \hline
    ${}$ & \textbf{Μέση Τιμή} & $323$ & $284$ & $237$ & $78$ & $22.4$ & $11.2$ & $6$ & $0.3$ & $4.2$ & $13$ & $26.8$\\
    \hline
    ${}$ & \textbf{Απόκλιση} & $55$ & $31$ & $24$ & $1$ & $16.6$ & $4.9$ & $2$ & $0.2$ & $1.8$ & $4$ & $5.3$\\
    \hline
    ${}$ & \textbf{Σχετικό Σφάλμα(\%)} & $17$ & $11$ & $10$ & $1$ & $74$ & $44$ & $33$ & $67$ & $43$ & $31$ & $20$\\
    \hline
    \hline
    ${}$ & $\textbf{Υψόμετρο}$ & $220\;m$ & ${}$ & \textbf{Πίεση} & $1000$ \newline \eng{mbar} & ${}$ &\textbf{Γεωγραφικό \newline Πλάτος} & $37.58^o$ & ${}$ & \textbf{Γεωγραφικό \newline Μήκος} & $23.46^o$ &  ${}$\\
    \hline
\end{supertabular}
\sq
\end{center}
\caption{\sq Τα αποτελέσματα των μετρήσεων(\eng{SI=Solar Irradiance})}\\.\indent     \hspace{8cm} Η τοπική ώρα είναι χειμερινή ώρα Ελλάδος(\eng{UTC+2}).
    \label{tab:measurements}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\hline

        {} & \textbf{\eng{Time} \eng{(UT)}\newline \eng{(hh:mm:ss)}} &     $\mathbf{O_3(corr)}$ \newline \textbf{\eng{(DU)}} & $\mathbf{O_3(1/2)}$ \newline \textbf{\eng{(DU)}} & $\mathbf{O_3(2/3)}$ \newline \textbf{\eng{(DU)}} & \textbf{\eng{SZA}} \newline \eng{({}$\mathbf{{}^o}$)} & \textbf{\eng{SI}}\newline($\mathbf{305nm}$) \newline ($\mathbf{\times 10^{-6}}$)\newline ($\mathbf{W/m^2}$) & \textbf{\eng{SI}}\newline($\mathbf{312nm}$) \newline ($\mathbf{\times 10^{-4}}$)\newline ($\mathbf{W/m^2}$) & \textbf{\eng{SI}}\newline($\mathbf{320nm}$) \newline ($\mathbf{\times 10^{-3}}$)\newline ($\mathbf{W/m^2}$) & \textbf{\eng{Signal}}\newline($\mathbf{305nm}$) \newline \textbf{(\eng{mV})} &  \textbf{\eng{Signal}}\newline($\mathbf{312nm}$) \newline \textbf{(\eng{mV})} &  \textbf{\eng{Signal}}\newline($\mathbf{320nm}$) \newline \textbf{(\eng{mV})} & \textbf{T} \newline ({}$\mathbf{{}^oC}$)\\
    \hline
    ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{1}$ & $13:42:28$ & $287.1$ & $264.7$ & $231.4$ & $77.023$ & $46.6$ & $17.9$ & $8.78$ & $0.63$ & $6.73$ & $16.95$ & $24.9$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{2}$ & $13:45:05$ & $294.1$ & $267.6$ & $229.9$ & $77.415$ & $34.2$ & $15.1$ & $7.64$ & $0.46$ & $5.66$ & $16.48$ & $25.3$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{3}$ & $13:47:33$ & $294.6$ & $267.6$ & $229.1$ & $77.788$ & $26.3$ & $12.7$ & $6.71$ & $0.36$ & $4.79$ & $14.47$ & $25.1$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{4}$ & $13:51:19$ & $306.7$ & $273.8$ & $286.9$ & $78.361$ & $15.7$ & $9.08$ & $5.39$ & $0.21$ & $3.64$ & $11.63$ & $24.7$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{5}$ & $13:54:20$ & $323.0$ & $282.9$ & $225.7$ & $78.824$ & $9.71$ & $7.75$ & $4.55$ & $0.13$ & $2.92$ & $9.82$ & $37.6$\\
    \hline
    $\mathbf{6}$ & $--:--:--$ & $432.1$ & $345.6$ & $221.8$ & $79.818$ & $1.68$ & $4.65$ & $3.07$ & $0.02$ & $1.75$ & $6.62$ & $23.5$\\
    \hline
    \hline
    ${}$ & \textbf{Μέση Τιμή} & $323$ & $284$ & $237$ & $78$ & $22.4$ & $11.2$ & $6$ & $0.3$ & $4.2$ & $13$ & $26.8$\\
    \hline
    ${}$ & \textbf{Απόκλιση} & $55$ & $31$ & $24$ & $1$ & $16.6$ & $4.9$ & $2$ & $0.2$ & $1.8$ & $4$ & $5.3$\\
    \hline
        ${}$ & \textbf{Σχετικό Σφάλμα(\%)} & $17$ & $11$ & $10$ & $1$ & $74$ & $44$     & $33$ & $67$ & $43$ & $31$ & $20$\\
        \hline
        \hline
        ${}$ & $\textbf{Υψόμετρο}$ & $220\;m$ & ${}$ & \textbf{Πίεση} & $1000$     \newline \eng{mbar} & ${}$ &\textbf{Γεωγραφικό \newline Πλάτος} & $37.58^o$ & ${}$ &     \textbf{Γεωγραφικό \newline Μήκος} & $23.46^o$ &  ${}$\\
        \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Solution~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\tablefirsthead {% 
\hline
\textbf{Λεπτά} \newline \textbf{\eng{(min)}} & \textbf{\eng{UV Index}} \newline οργάνου &     \textbf{\eng{UV Index}} \newline \textbf{($mW/m^2$)} &  \textbf{\eng{MED}} \newline οργάνου     & \textbf{\eng{MED/hr}} \newline  \textbf{($mW/m^2$)} & \textbf{\eng{MED*}} \newline     (\eng{MED/min}) &\textbf{\eng{EUVD}} \newline \textbf{($J/m^2$)} & \textbf{\eng{SZA}}     \newline \textbf{(\eng{degrees})}\\ 
\hline
}
\tablehead{%
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|r|}{Συνέχεια από προηγούμενη σελίδα $...$ } \\
\hline
}
\tabletail{%
\hline   
\multicolumn{8}{|r|}{Συνέχεια στην επόμενη σελίδα $...$ } \\
\hline
}
\tablelasttail{
\hline
}
\bottomcaption{Πειραματικές Μετρήσεις}
\label{tab:measurements}

\begin{supertabular}{C{1.2cm}C{1.8cm}C{1.8cm}C{1.4cm}C{1.7cm}C{2cm}C{1.3cm}C{1.7cm}}

            ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$ & ${}$\\
    $0$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0$ & $0.86$ & $0$ & $0$ & $72.11$\\
    $1$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0$ & $0.86$ & $0$ & ${}$ & $72.24$\\
    $2$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0$ & $0.86$ & $0$ & ${}$ & $72.37$\\
    $3$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0$ & $0.86$ & $0$ & ${}$ & $72.50$\\
    $4$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0$ & $0.86$ & $0$ & ${}$ & $72.63$\\
    $5$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.02$ & $21$ & $72.76$\\
    $6$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $72.89$\\
    $7$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $73.02$\\
    $8$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $73.15$\\
    $9$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $73.28$\\
    $10$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $73.41$\\
    $11$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $73.55$\\
    $12$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $73.68$\\
    $13$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $73.81$\\
    $14$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $73.95$\\
    $15$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $74.08$\\
    $16$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.1$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $74.22$\\
    $17$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & $42$ & $74.35$\\
    $18$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $74.49$\\
    $19$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $74.63$\\
    $20$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $74.76$\\
    $21$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $74.90$\\
    $22$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $75.04$\\
    $23$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $75.18$\\
    $24$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $75.32$\\
    $25$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $75.46$\\
    $26$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $75.60$\\
    $27$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $75.74$\\
    $28$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $75.88$\\
    $29$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $76.02$\\
    $30$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.2$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $76.16$\\
    $31$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & $63$ & $76.31$\\
    $32$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $76.45$\\
    $33$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $76.59$\\
    $34$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $76.74$\\
    $35$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $76.88$\\
    $36$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $77.03$\\
    $37$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $77.17$\\
    $38$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $77.32$\\
    $39$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $77.46$\\
    $40$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $77.61$\\
    $41$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $77.76$\\
    $42$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $77.90$\\
    $43$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $78.05$\\
    $44$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.3$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $78.20$\\
    $45$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.4$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & $84$ & $78.35$\\
    $46$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.4$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $78.50$\\
    $47$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.4$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $78.65$\\
    $48$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.4$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $78.80$\\
    $49$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.4$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $78.95$\\
    $50$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.4$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $79.10$\\
    $51$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.4$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $79.25$\\
    $52$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.4$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $79.40$\\
    $53$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.4$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $79.55$\\
    $54$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.4$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $79.70$\\
    $55$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.4$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $79.86$\\
    $56$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.5$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & $105$ & $80.01$\\
    $57$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.5$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $80.16$\\
    $58$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.5$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $80.31$\\
    $59$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.5$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $80.47$\\
    $60$ & $2$ & $50$ & $0.5$ & $0.86$ & $0.01$ & ${}$ & $80.62$\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{center}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

It is really ugly I know, it rather big;yes you are right and has a lot of errors(188). There are errors(~28) that have to do with alignment on the first table `C{2cm}`, which I don't know how to fix... There are other errors that have to do with probably the fact that I cannot have multicols in a longtable.

Comment: What problem did you run into when you tried to combine `supertabular` and `landscape`? Please post the code here so those trying to help have something to start with.   While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: As well, I think that it is somehow possible to combine `lscape` and `longtable`, see this answer by David Carlisle: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63592/11002 Remember that `longtable` has quite a special formatting, see [its manual here](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable).

Comment: @tohecz `lscape` was _written_ for `longtable` :-)

Comment: @PeterGrill: I didn't try to combine them...That's why am I asking about the optimum way to achieve that!

Comment: You should definitely include some attempt. Even if it's totally different to an eventual solution, it shows that you've put some effort into the problem and it will still be good for setting up a shell document. Also a tip; vertical lines are normally bad. Many journals actually remove them since they add little but clutter. I'll refrain from the usual comic sans rant. ;)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The problem is that I want to have multicolumns and as I saw from the CTAN this cannot be achieved with  tex.stackexchange.com/a/63592/11002

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I added some effort but it's uggly...Check my edited answer!

Comment: do you mean multicolumns as in table spanning `\multicolumn` (for which there should be no problem) or do you mean a multi column pag elayout as in `multicols` package, wrapping a landscape table over multiple columns within a single page might be... odd?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I mean `\multicolumn` i.e. to split one column of a table in 3 let's say...

Comment: well neither longtable nor supertab should have any problems with `\multicolumn` did you try?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Actually I did.But it didn't work. Please check my edited question ;)

Comment: you are loading supertabular but not using it you have used a normal tabular and put it in a [H] table (which is a minipage) so it can not break over a page or float.

Comment: The error message in the MWE is `! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.` which is simply that you have used `C` which is not a legal column specification, you would need to define it with `\newcolumntype`. Please edit your MWE so that it runs without unrelated errors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry for the `\newcolumntype`...I have updated my effort. I also replaced `tabular` with `supertabular`... So the first table is working!!!It is really produced rotated...In the second table however, my compiler cannot recognise `longtable` enviroment...

Comment: my compiler cannot recognise longtable enviroment.  well you haven't loaded the longtable package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You are abolutely right...However I think I found a  solution!!!And I am very happy about it! You can fing it on the very end of my question!

Comment: I used `supertabular` and `landscape`. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Just to not leave this question open.

Both `supertabular` and `longtable` may be used in a `landscape` environment, but in either case it is necessary to load the appropriate package and use the `supertabular` or `longtable` *directly* inside the `landscape` not inside a `table` environment or other floating or box construct.