# How to break longtable in landscape mode automatically?

Tags: longtable, sidewaystable

I want to break a very long table in using `\longtable` and in sideways environment to break between pages automatically. My working code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,rotating}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
        \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.1mm}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
            \caption{Unipotent matrix of EEG signals of Patient $A$ at time $t=1$ to $t=15$ written as a summation of their respective semisimple and nilpotent parts}
            \label{table:JCD-of-diagonal}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{Time ($t$)} & \textbf{Unipotent matrix of EEG signals}  &   \textbf{Semisimple $+$ Nilpotent}  \\
            \hline
            \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{3}{c}%
            {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Time ($t$)} & \textbf{Unipotent matrix of EEG signals}  &   \textbf{Semisimple $+$ Nilpotent}  \\
            \hline
            \endhead
            \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
            \endfoot
            \hline
            \endlastfoot
            1 & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & -1.7693 & 2.3933    & 3.5579    \\
                0 & 1       & -0.7405   & -1.4740   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & -1.8018   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                0 & -1.7693 & 2.3933    & 3.5579    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.7405   & -1.4740   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & -1.8018   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            2 & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0.5468  & -0.8309   & 8.8955    \\
                0 & 1       & 2.4452    & 6.6199    \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & 3.3119    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                0 & 0.5468  & -0.8309   & 8.8955    \\
                0 & 0       & 2.4452    & 6.6199    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 3.3119    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            3 & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 1.4185  & -0.2744   & -15.9462  \\
                0 & 1       & -3.8254   & -11.4390  \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & 1.1833    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                0 & 1.4185  & -0.2744   & -15.9462  \\
                0 & 0       & -3.8254   & -11.4390  \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1.1833    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            4 & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & -0.4499 & 15.5040   & 1.2788    \\
                0 & 1       & 13.9690   & -0.8115   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & 0.4189    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                0 & -0.4499 & 15.5040   & 1.2788    \\
                0 & 0       & 13.9690   & -0.8115   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0.4189    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            5 & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & -1.3695 & -22.3137  & 0.4863    \\
                0 & 1       & -3.9190   & -0.1132   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & 0.3099    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                0 & -1.3695 & -22.3137  & 0.4863    \\
                0 & 0       & -3.9190   & -0.1132   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0.3099    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            6 & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & -0.8564 & -1.4359   & 1.4699    \\
                0 & 1       & -0.1128   & -4404 \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & 20.473    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                0 & -0.8564 & -1.4359   & 1.4699    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.1128   & -4404 \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 20.473    \\
                    0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            7 & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & -1.2084 & 20.7007   & -1.0977   \\
                0 & 1       & 4.9237    & -0.2032   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & -0.0381   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                0 & -0.8564 & -1.4359   & 1.4699    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.1128   & -0.2032   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & -0.0381   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
                \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            8 & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 1       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                0 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            8 & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 1       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                0 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            8 & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 1       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                0 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
        \end{longtable}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You could use use a landscape environment instead of the sidewaystable. (Needs the pdflscape package.)

Comment: See also: [Sidewaystable together with longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63585/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in aprevious comment, you can use `longtable` inside of a `landscape` environment from the `pdflscape` package in order to get a rotated table that spans multiple pages. In the following MWE, I additionally made some adjustments in order to improve alignment and spacing. The whole table should now easily fit onto two pages.

Here is a screenhot of the first page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,pdflscape,array}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{.5\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth}
        \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.1mm}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{9pt}
%        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \begin{longtable}{|0c|0c|0c|}
            \caption{Unipotent matrix of EEG signals of Patient $A$ at time $t=1$ to $t=15$ written as a summation of their respective semisimple and nilpotent parts}
            \label{table:JCD-of-diagonal}\\
            \hline
            \textbf{Time ($t$)} & \textbf{Unipotent matrix of EEG signals}  &   \textbf{Semisimple $+$ Nilpotent}  \\
            \hline
            \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{3}{c}%
            {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Time ($t$)} & \textbf{Unipotent matrix of EEG signals}  &   \textbf{Semisimple $+$ Nilpotent}  \\
            \hline
            \endhead
            \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
            \endfoot
            \hline
            \endlastfoot
            1 & $\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                1 & -1.7693 & 2.3933    & 3.5579    \\
                0 & 1       & -0.7405   & -1.4740   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & -1.8018   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                0 & -1.7693 & 2.3933    & 3.5579    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.7405   & -1.4740   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & -1.8018   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            2 & $\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                1 & 0.5468  & -0.8309   & 8.8955    \\
                0 & 1       & 2.4452    & 6.6199    \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & 3.3119    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                0 & 0.5468  & -0.8309   & 8.8955    \\
                0 & 0       & 2.4452    & 6.6199    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 3.3119    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            3 & $\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                1 & 1.4185  & -0.2744   & -15.9462  \\
                0 & 1       & -3.8254   & -11.4390  \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & 1.1833    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                0 & 1.4185  & -0.2744   & -15.9462  \\
                0 & 0       & -3.8254   & -11.4390  \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1.1833    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            4 & $\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                1 & -0.4499 & 15.5040   & 1.2788    \\
                0 & 1       & 13.9690   & -0.8115   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & 0.4189    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                0 & -0.4499 & 15.5040   & 1.2788    \\
                0 & 0       & 13.9690   & -0.8115   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0.4189    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            5 & $\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                1 & -1.3695 & -22.3137  & 0.4863    \\
                0 & 1       & -3.9190   & -0.1132   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & 0.3099    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                0 & -1.3695 & -22.3137  & 0.4863    \\
                0 & 0       & -3.9190   & -0.1132   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0.3099    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            6 & $\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                1 & -0.8564 & -1.4359   & 1.4699    \\
                0 & 1       & -0.1128   & -4404 \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & 20.473    \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                0 & -0.8564 & -1.4359   & 1.4699    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.1128   & -4404 \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 20.473    \\
                    0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            7 & $\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                1 & -1.2084 & 20.7007   & -1.0977   \\
                0 & 1       & 4.9237    & -0.2032   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & -0.0381   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                0 & -0.8564 & -1.4359   & 1.4699    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.1128   & -0.2032   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & -0.0381   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
                \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            8 & $\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                1 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 1       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                0 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            8 & $\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                1 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 1       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                0 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
            8 & $\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                1 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 1       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 1         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 1
            \end{array}\right)$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
                1 & 0 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 1 & 0   \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 1
            \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c*{3}{wc{3em}}}
                0 & 0.3065  & -0.5738   & 0.7648    \\
                0 & 0       & -0.6329   & -2.0170   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & -2.1552   \\
                0 & 0       & 0         & 0
            \end{array}\right)$ \\ \hline
        \end{longtable}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```